# How to update column value based on records existing in two different tables?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

Is there a better way of doing the following? (Instead of having two separate queries) I want to update the UserTypeId column to either '`USER1`'
or '`USER2`' if a record exists in the AdminDetails table.

```
UPDATE Usernames
SET UserTypeId = (select Id from UserTypes where code = 'USER1')
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT AdminDetails.Id
FROM AdminDetails
WHERE AdminDetails.Id = Usernames.Id)

UPDATE Usernames
SET UserTypeId = (select Id from UserTypes where code = 'USER2')
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT AdminDetails.Id
FROM AdminDetails
WHERE AdminDetails.Id = Usernames.Id)
```

I tried using `COUNT()` but I got the following error when attempting to do this in one query using an inner join and case statement:

```
UPDATE  Usernames
SET     UserTypeId = (CASE WHEN COUNT(AdminDetails.Id) > 0 THEN 'USER1' ELSE 'USER2' END)
FROM    AdminDetails
        INNER JOIN Usernames AS un
            ON  AdminDetails.Id = un.UserId
```

But it gives the following error: '**An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement**'.

I  want to do this in one query using case when then else by checking if a record exists. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, using `EXISTS` within the `CASE` statement:

```
UPDATE  Usernames
SET     UserTypeId = (CASE WHEN EXISTS 
                                (SELECT AdminDetails.Id
                                 FROM AdminDetails
                                 WHERE AdminDetails.Id = Usernames.Id) 
                           THEN 'USER1' ELSE 'USER2' END)
```

**NOTE:** This would update all records where the IDs are in both tables unless you add a `WHERE` clause on to it. Also, I'm not sure that you would want to update the `UserTypeId` with the values `USER1` and `USER2`, which is what your third `UPDATE` statement is trying to do. Without seeing your full database schema it's hard to be exact.